# Detect change of an element and set it back to before?

Tags: javascript, jquery, element

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#u22_input").on("change keyup paste", function () {
        $('#u25_img').attr('src', '');
    })

    if ($("#u22_input").val()) {
        $('#u25_img').attr('src', 'images/shirtnew/u25.png');
    }

});
```

Trying to detect the change of an text input which is working properly now..

But how to change the `#u25_img` src to its original value when text input (`#u22_input`) is empty?

Comment: Move the `if` statement into the handler.

Comment: This question has been answered in comments

Answer (score 1):

You can move the `if` statement into your event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#u22_input").on("change keyup paste", function () {
        // Using a ternary operator instead of `if`
        // and trimming the value
        var src = $.trim(this.value).length > 0
                  ? 'images/shirtnew/u25.png'
                  : '';
        $('#u25_img').attr('src', src);
    });
});
```

If you want to execute the handler once on DOM ready you can trigger one of the events that your handler listens to:

```
$("#u22_input").on("change keyup paste", function () {
    var src = $.trim(this.value).length > 0 
              ? 'images/shirtnew/u25.png'
              : '';
    $('#u25_img').attr('src', src);
}).trigger('change'); // execute the handler immediately
```

Comment: Sure... or just add yours and I delete mine :)